# DataFrame Panda: if-elif.. if block is not picked up

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

CSV is formatted as:
[image]

Dataframe is:
[image]

I am trying to achieve a if conditions. But it executes  the else block and outcomes are always "Value3".Where I am going wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste actual code and data so people can try it out themselves, and not pictures

Comment: def validate(row):
 
    if  row['TRANSACTION DESC']=='JWPFMAIN':
        val="Value1"
       
    if row['TRANSACTION CD']==' ':
        val="Value2"
        
   
    else:
        val="Value3"
       
    return val
        
        
dfwithcolumns['Status'] = dfwithcolumns.apply(validate, axis=1)

Comment: What is the value in the empty cells? Is it `' '`, i.e. a space? Or is it `''`, the empty string, or maybe something else?

Comment: It is a space. '     '

Comment: Can you also paste a sample of your data? There might be a space in front of the value JWPFMAIN

Comment: Yes. There are few spaces after JWPFMAIN.. How can we trim the value in the dataframe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add strip as given below:

```
def validate(row): 
  if row['TRANSACTION DESC'].strip()=='JWPFMAIN': 
    val="Value1" 
  elif row['TRANSACTION CD'].strip()=='': 
    val="Value2" 
  else: 
    val="Value3" 
  return val 

dfwithcolumns['Status'] = dfwithcolumns.apply(validate, axis=1)
```

Comment: If it's already a string value, you don't need `str.strip()` just `strip()` will do

Answer (score 0):

Try to use elif instead of the second if. Because then if the first one is true but the second if statement is false then the val would default to value3. Also make sure that for the second if statement that it is a space, because it could also be a '' empty string.